# Unable to connect to mysql in AWS

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-boot

My spring boot application is throwing error when I run the jar in AWS EC2 instance. It works fine when I run in my local system.

My `application.properties` file is

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gbi?    useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=fa    lse&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconne    cts=10
spring.jpa.database-platform =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.datasource.username=******
spring.datasource.password=******@
spring.datasource.pool.size=20
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8090
```

When I run the jar in AWS server, I get the following error

```
 Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 10 
times. Giving up.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

followed by,

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native 
Method)
atsun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

followed by,

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection 
refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
atjava.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
```

followed by,

```
2017-Oct-09 15:24:49.735 WARN  [main] o.s.b.a.o.j.DatabaseLookup - 
Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get 
Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get 
JDBC Connection; nested exception is 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 10 
times. Giving up.
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Got to Ec2 and click on Security Groups then in the bottom add a new security group with type as MYSQL/Aurora protocal as TCP and select the port number and then in source select your computer's Ip Address. 
You should be able to resolve your issue.

Thanks,
Madhu

Comment: What do you mean "my computer's ip"? Should I put the ip of computer from where I deploy jar??

Comment: I thought it's an application in your local so i said to put the IP address of your local machine. if that is not, then create a security group and add it in the inbound rules

Comment: Hi! I've tried the same method but didn't work for me. I've created an rds instance of postresql, connected it to my spring boot app and when launching locally, it works fine, but in EBS it doesn't work.